# Accessing API with C# with CURL examples

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, curl

So I'm trying to access a client's API to ultimately build a product feed.  Their API Dev Docs show examples using curl commands.  I"m wondering if someone can help me figure out how to achieve the same thing in C# (either a command line exe, or an asp.net app).

1. I first need to create a session.

The curl example:

`curl -v -u {client_id}:{client_secret} "https://www.clientsite.com/api/v2.0/sessionid"`

2. Then I need to call the API for products with the session just created (A cookie named JSESSIONID is created).

The curl example:

```
curl -v -u {client_id}:{client_secret} "https://www.clientsite.com/api/v2.0/products;jsessionid={jsessionid}"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So what did you try? `curl -u user:pass`  simply performs basic authentication, which you can read in the manual. So search for "C# http request basic authentication", and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Right, but the part I"m having a problem with is getting the session ID and passing it into my product query.

Comment: Then please edit that into your question. It's unclear what code you have and what exactly you want it to do.